# how to combine column which value is varchar after group by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In oracle I have a table like below

```
ID   Name   Location
001  John      A
002  peter     A
003  Jack      B
004  Dennis    C
```

how to get ID+Name group by location
the result is like

```
 001_John;002_peter    A
    003_Jack              B
    004_Dennis            c
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following query with listagg function

```
SELECT 
    location,
    LISTAGG(id||'_'||name), ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id,name) "names"
FROM table_x
GROUP BY location
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[wm_concat()](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_wm_concat_sql_function.htm)** in oracle to do it

```
SELECT location,wm_concat(t.id||'_'||t.name)
FROM yourtable t 
group by t.location
```

Comment: you should concatenate id with name, not location